# How to create a tableView in DetailViewController of SPLITVIEWCONTROLLER ? (IPAD)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

What I all want is to display a tableView in the detailView of the splitviewController.., I could find only ImageView samples in other sites.., Would be great if Anyone let me know how it is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UITableViewController and add it's view to the DetailViewControllers view as a subview:

```
    UITableViewController *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView.view];
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: What I all want is to display a tableView in the detailView of the splitviewController.., I cpuld find only ImageView samples in other sites.., Would be great if Anyone let me know how it is done..

Comment: If you put the code above in the ViewDidLoad method of your DetailViewController then it will add a UITableViewController to its view. So the code above does do what you require.

Comment: Am a novice xcode developer, One last Query !!..
Before, I used to perform cellforRowAtIndexPath and used to define numberofrows and sections to display a tableView on the screen.., Can I know.., How do I do it using a UITableViewController.. How to set the data that has to be presented in the cells [it may be simple.., but im new to this.. Thanks ]

Comment: Thanks for ya response earlier. I figured it out